# persist ddl values and selected value in between postbacks

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a save button and a drop down list on a page. Inside the page Load, the drop down list is populated if !Page.PostBack (AutoPostBack=false). So, the first time I load the page, the drop down list is populated. I also have a save method to go with the save button. When this button is clicked, it should do something with the selected value of the drop down list. My problem is that the drop down list has no value (is null) inside the button save method. How would you fix this?

Markup:

MyClass.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="MyClass"  %>


<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainRegion" runat="server">

<div>

<asp:DropDownList ID="myDdl" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="myDdlChange" ViewStateMode="Enabled" EnableViewState="true" />
</div>
<br />

<div style="min-width: 300px; max-width: 770px;">
<asp:TextBox id="txtBox" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" />
</div>

<div class="buttonContainer">
    <span >
        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" onclick="btnSave_Click"  />   
    </span>
</div>

</asp:Content>
```

Then, in the code behind:

MyClass.aspx.cs

```
public class MyClass
    {
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList myDdl;
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txtBox;
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button btnSave;


        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {

            base.OnLoad(e);

            if (this.Page.IsPostBack)
                Session["selectedID"] = myDdl.SelectedValue; // my attempt to put the selected value from ddl in a session var, to use it later inside the save method but it didn't work

            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                //create array1 here
                myDdl.Items.Clear();
                myDdl.Items.AddRange(array1); 
                Session["selectedID"] = myDdl.SelectedValue;

                myDdlChange(null, null);
                this.DataBind();
            }
        }

        protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //do something based on myDdl.SelectedValue (which shouldn't be null)

        }

        protected void myDdlChange(object source, EventArgs e)
        {

            txtBox.Text = myDdl.SelectedValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main problem is you should be using `Page_Load` instead of `OnLoad`.

You don't need to use Session to remember the SelectedValue.

Try something like this which works for me...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        PopulateDropdown();
}

private void PopulateDropdown()
{
    myDdl.Items.Clear();
    var array1 = new ListItem[3];
    array1[0] = new ListItem("item1", "item1");
    array1[1] = new ListItem("item2", "item2");
    array1[2] = new ListItem("item3", "item3");
    myDdl.Items.AddRange(array1);
    myDdl.DataBind();
}

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selectedVal = myDdl.SelectedValue;  // putting a breakpoint here shows myDdl.SelectedValue is not null
}

protected void myDdlChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks Scotty, there is a problem with myDdl value however. it doesn't remember its value when inside the save method during postback.

Comment: Also, unless the myDdlChange is explicitly called, it's never triggered.

Comment: @dear1 are you using Page_Load now? Please post your updated code as it appears exactly.

Comment: Works perfect. I had an option in config EnableViewStateMode=false. Had to Switch it to true.